# Get the name of an uploaded file

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

I'm uploading a file using curl:

```
 curl -X POST --data-binary @/home/me/my_file.jpb localhost:9001/upload
```

And here is how to store it:

```
def upload = Action(parse.temporaryFile) {
    request =>
      import java.io.File

      val f = new File("tmp/someName") // how do I get the name of the file being uploaded?
      request.body.moveTo(f, true)
      Ok("File uploaded\n")
  }
```

Note that files can be in any format. I want to get the name of the actually uploaded file. I tried `request.body.file.getName` but it returns gibberish.

How do I do that?

Comment: If all else fails, sniff the wire (port 9001). I'm pretty sure @Vidya is right and that "my_file.jpb" will not appear anywhere in the transmitted data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am fairly certain you cannot get the file name from the binary stream you are uploading via curl. You need to explicitly provide the file name separately.

The options I can think of are these:

- If your `Content-Type` header is instead `multipart/form-data`, then the process is quite simple as described [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaFileUpload)
- Upload JSON with a `String` for the file name and a binary portion for the file.